# Complex Trigonometric Equation?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having difficulty solving

$$\cos (z) = \sqrt2$$

In class it was mentioned using the quadratic formula to solve for the inverse cos function but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: So are complex solutions allowed here? Because otherwise it won't work

Answer (score 3):

Notice, we have $$\cos z=\sqrt2$$
$$\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}=\sqrt2$$
$$\frac{e^{2iz}+1}{2e^{iz}}=\sqrt2$$
$$e^{2iz}+1=2\sqrt2e^{iz}$$
$$(e^{iz})^2-2\sqrt2e^{iz}+1=0$$
Above is the quadratic equation in terms of $e^{iz}$ hence using quadratic formula $$e^{iz}=\frac{2\sqrt2\pm\sqrt{(2\sqrt2)^2-4(1)(1)}}{2(1)}$$$$e^{iz}=\sqrt 2\pm 1$$
$$iz=\ln(\sqrt 2\pm1)$$$$\color{blue}{z=-i\ln(\sqrt 2\pm1)}$$

Comment: could you color your final result with green/blue since red is mostly associated with being wrong, wrong answer, etc. ;)

Comment: Alright, you can check it

Comment: that's more like it +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

You have 
$$e^iz + e^{-iz} = 2\sqrt{2}. $$
so 
$$e^{2iz} + 1 = 2\sqrt{2}e^{iz}. $$
Put $w = e^{iz}$; this becomes
$$w^2 + 1 = 2\sqrt{2} w.$$
This is a quadratic.

Comment: Just to clarify it should be $e^{iz}$ correct?

Comment: so changed; I'd prefer an edit to a downvote.